# Linux: rename files in loop while only targeting the first instance of a specific character

Tags: shell, command-line, rename

This thread (https://superuser.com/questions/659876/how-to-rename-files-and-replace-characters) has proven bountiful and does what I need it to do, except, I need to replace just the first instance of a character in a filename.

How can I make it so that this:

```
for f in *:*; do mv -v "$f" $(echo "$f" | tr '.' '_'); done
```

Only replaces the first instance of `.` in a filename, with a filename such as:

```
2022-10-07T071101.8495077Z_QueryHistory.txt
```

Comment: For questions related to Linux, I recommend looking on [unix.se] rather than [su]. The answers tend to have higher quality.

Comment: You may want to try the `rename` command (the Larry Wall one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the method you tried is more complex than it needs to be, and fragile (it breaks if file names contain certain special characters). Here's a simpler method relying on [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to transform the file name:

```
for f in *; do mv -v -- "$f" "${f/./_}"; done   # replace the first .
for f in *; do mv -v -- "$f" "${f//./_}"; done  # replace every .
```

This requires bash, ksh or zsh as the shell: other shells such as dash (which is Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`, so commonly used for scripting, but hardly ever used interactively) don't have the `${VARIABLE/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` form of parameter expansion.

Alternatively, you can use `prename` (`apt install rename`):

```
rename 's/\./_/' *     # replace the first .
rename 's/\./_/g' *    # replace every .
```

Alternatively, you can use [zsh](https://www.slideshare.net/jaguardesignstudio/why-zsh-is-cooler-than-your-shell-16194692)'s [zmv](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

```
autoload -U zmv   # put this in your .zshrc
zmv '*' '${f/./_}'        # replace the first .
zmv -W '*.*.*' '*_*.*'    # replace the next-to-last .
zmv '*' '${f//./_}'       # replace every .
```

All the snippets in my answer skip files whose name begins with a dot.

Comment: Amazing -- any chance you comment / update for the following situation: if the filename has two periods, execute the rename operation, else do nothing (so repeated execution of the script does not remove the file-extension.

Comment: @JohnStud Instead of replacing all files matching `*`, only replace files matching `*.*.*` (or some more precise pattern). The “replace the next-to-last .” solution already does this.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Perl's `rename` commandline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574):

```
    rename -n 's/\./_/' ./2022-10-07T071101.8495077Z_QueryHistory.txt
```

Remove `-n` (aka `dry-run`) when the output looks satisfactory.