# Linux: Rename files if condition is first met

Tags: shell, command-line, rename

This is a continuation of a related but separate ask to this question: [Linux: rename files in loop while only targeting the first instance of a specific character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720180/linux-rename-files-in-loop-while-only-targeting-the-first-instance-of-a-specifi)

This code works exceptionally well for me to replace the first period from filenames such as: `2022-10-07T071101.8495077Z_QueryHistory.txt`

```
for f in *; do mv -v -- "$f" "${f/./_}"; done   # replace the first .
```

However, I need to run this regularly on a directory and I do not want to eventually replace the file extension `.txt`.

How can I run this command: `for f in *; do mv -v -- "$f" "${f/./_}"; done`, such that it only runs if it can find two `.` in the filename.

Comment: `for f in *; do if [[ "$f" == *.*.* ]] ; then mv -v -- "$f" "${f/./_}"; fi ; done`?

Comment: `for f in *.*.*; do if [ "$f" != '*.*.*' ] ; then mv -v -- "$f" "${f/./_}"; fi; done`. If you use `bash` you can simplify this and omit the `if...then...fi` if you use `shopt -s nullglob` before and `shopt -u nullglob` after the `for` loop.

Comment: These are working solutions, thank you!

Comment: You may want to try the `rename` command (the Larry Wall one).